# Google Charts: Uncaught ReferenceError: data is not defined and mixed Content

Tags: google-apps-script, google-visualization

I am trying to draw chart from the array of data and failed. I tried everything. please advice. There is the code. I got two message error: Uncaught ReferenceError: data is not defined and Mixed Content: The page at 'https://n-ynglt762zsbkrcsxo6kvcrifknrgdiycdteawcy-script.googleusercontent.com/userCodeAppPanel' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure script 'http://www.google.com/jsapi'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.

```
 <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
 <head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
  <title>
  Google Visualization API Sample
</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  google.load('visualization', '1.1', {packages: ['corechart', 'controls']});
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">


google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["controls"]});
  google.setOnLoadCallback(drawVisualization);


            function drawVisualization() {
                var dashboard = new google.visualization.Dashboard(document.getElementById('dashboard'));

     var control = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper({
        'controlType': 'ChartRangeFilter',
        'containerId': 'control',
        'options': {
            // Filter by the date axis.
            'filterColumnIndex': 0,
            'ui': {
                'chartType': 'LineChart',
                'chartOptions': {
                    'chartArea': {'width': '90%'},
                    'hAxis': {'baselineColor': 'none'}
                },
                'chartView': {
                    'columns': [0, 1, 2]
                },
                'minRangeSize': 1
            }
        },
        // Initial range: 1 to 4.
        'state': {'range': {'start': 1, 'end': 4}},
        view: {
            columns: [{
                type: 'number',
                calc: function (dt, row) {
                    return {v: row, f: dt.getFormattedValue(row, 0)};
                }
            }, 1, 2]
        }
    });

    //then reverse the process in the ChartWrapper's view.columns:

    var chart = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
        'chartType': 'AreaChart',
        'containerId': 'chart',
        'options': {
            // Use the same chart area width as the control for axis alignment.
            'chartArea': {'height': '80%', 'width': '90%'},
            'hAxis': {'slantedText': false},
            'vAxis': {'viewWindow': {'min': 0, 'max': 20}},
            'legend': {'position': 'none'}
        },
        view: {
            columns: [{
                type: 'string',
                label: data.getColumnLabel(0),
                calc: function (dt, row) {
                    return dt.getFormattedValue(row, 0);
                }
            }, 1, 2]
        }
    });

  var dataTable = new google.visualization.DataTable();

    var query = new google.visualization.Query('https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1SphK7Dqcok03TEGaxL-sO7JkovXoYOO3rDbtKGEjjEU/edit#gid=0');

      var nowone = getNowDate();
      query.setQuery("select A,B,C where A >= datetime '"+nowone+"' ");
      query.send(handleQueryResponse);

                dashboard.bind(control, chart);
                dashboard.draw(data);

function getNowDate(){
var d=new Date();
d.setDate(d.getDate() - 1);

var year = d.getFullYear();  
var month = d.getMonth() + 1;
var day = d.getDate();
var hour = d.getHours();
var minute = d.getMinutes();
var second = d.getSeconds();
var microsecond = d.getDate();

if (month.toString().length == 1) {
    month = '0' + month;
}

if (day.toString().length == 1) {
    day = '0' + day;
}

if (hour.toString().length == 1) {
    hour = '0' + hour;
}

if (minute.toString().length == 1) {
    minute = '0' + minute;
}

if (second.toString().length == 1) {
    second = '0' + second;
}

//while(microsecond.toString().length < 3) {
//    microsecond = '0' + microsecond;
//}

var dateString = year + '-' + month + '-' + day + ' ' + hour + ':' + minute + ':' + second;
return dateString;
} 

function handleQueryResponse(response) {
    if (response.isError()) {
    alert('Error in query: ' + response.getMessage() + ' ' + response.getDetailedMessage());
    return;
    }

    var data = response.getDataTable();

 }
 }


        </script>
    </head>

    <body style="font-family: Arial;border: 0 none;">
        <div id="dashboard" style="width:1300px;overflow:scroll;">
            <div id="chart" style="position: relative; width: 1300px; height: 300px;"></div>
            <div id="control"></div>
        </div>
        <div id="junk_div" style="display: none;"></div>
    </body>

</html>
```

I appreciate your attention to this question. I still don't get it the 'data' is defined within drawVisualization. . I have two similar code working I would like to share...

[code1 working](https://script.google.com/macros/d/10m1zAWYlv3qSluJwnbJmrswItyNEPV0kKDUEKLVtRdh6Na9MkrS2rcfT/edit?usp=drive_web)
[code2 working](https://script.google.com/macros/d/15nw_1YfOiqiC2C8llPPS6GzjEAX7M2d0cNfiekCrSCuUx2jERA0DZndr/edit?usp=drive_web)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go, a full working solution for you:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="https://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
 <head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
  <title>
    Google Visualization API Sample
  </title>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    google.load('visualization', '1.1', {packages: ['corechart', 'controls']});
  </script>

 </head>

<body style="font-family: Arial;border: 0 none;">
        <div id="dashboard" style="width:1300px;overflow:scroll;">
            <div id="chart" style="position: relative; width: 1300px; height: 300px;"></div>
            <div id="control"></div>
        </div>

        <div id="junk_div" style="display: none;"></div>


<script type="text/javascript">

var data;
var dataTable;
var dashboard;

google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["controls"]});
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawVisualization);

function setupData(){
  var control = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper({
        'controlType': 'ChartRangeFilter',
        'containerId': 'control',
        'options': {
            // Filter by the date axis.
            'filterColumnIndex': 0,
            'ui': {
                'chartType': 'LineChart',
                'chartOptions': {
                    'chartArea': {'width': '90%'},
                    'hAxis': {'baselineColor': 'none'}
                },
                'chartView': {
                    'columns': [0, 1, 2]
                },
                'minRangeSize': 1
            }
        },
        // Initial range: 1 to 4.
        'state': {'range': {'start': 1, 'end': 4}},
        view: {
            columns: [{
                type: 'number',
                calc: function (dt, row) {
                    return {v: row, f: dt.getFormattedValue(row, 0)};
                }
            }, 1, 2]
        }
    });

    //then reverse the process in the ChartWrapper's view.columns:

    var chart = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
        'chartType': 'AreaChart',
        'containerId': 'chart',
        'options': {
            // Use the same chart area width as the control for axis alignment.
            'chartArea': {'height': '80%', 'width': '90%'},
            'hAxis': {'slantedText': false},
            'vAxis': {'viewWindow': {'min': 0, 'max': 20}},
            'legend': {'position': 'none'}
        },
        view: {
            columns: [{
                type: 'string',
                label: data.getColumnLabel(0),
                calc: function (dt, row) {
                    return dt.getFormattedValue(row, 0);
                }
            }, 1, 2]
        }
    });
    console.log('label: ' + data.getColumnLabel(0));
    dashboard.bind(control, chart);
    dashboard.draw(data);

}

function drawVisualization() {

  dataTable = new google.visualization.DataTable();


  dashboard = new google.visualization.Dashboard(document.getElementById('dashboard'));

  var query = new google.visualization.Query('https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1SphK7Dqcok03TEGaxL-sO7JkovXoYOO3rDbtKGEjjEU/edit#gid=0');

  var nowone = getNowDate();
  query.setQuery("select A,B,C where A >= datetime '"+nowone+"' ");
  query.send(handleQueryResponse);

}

function getNowDate(){
  var d = new Date();
  d.setDate(d.getDate() - 1);

  var year = d.getFullYear();  
  var month = d.getMonth() + 1;
  var day = d.getDate();
  var hour = d.getHours();
  var minute = d.getMinutes();
  var second = d.getSeconds();
  var microsecond = d.getDate();

  if (month.toString().length == 1) {
      month = '0' + month;
  }

  if (day.toString().length == 1) {
      day = '0' + day;
  }

  if (hour.toString().length == 1) {
      hour = '0' + hour;
  }

  if (minute.toString().length == 1) {
      minute = '0' + minute;
  }

  if (second.toString().length == 1) {
      second = '0' + second;
  }

  //while(microsecond.toString().length < 3) {
  //    microsecond = '0' + microsecond;
  //}

  var dateString = year + '-' + month + '-' + day + ' ' + hour + ':' + minute + ':' + second;
  return dateString;
} 

function handleQueryResponse(response) {
    if (response.isError()) {
      alert('Error in query: ' + response.getMessage() + ' ' + response.getDetailedMessage());
    return;
    }

    data = response.getDataTable();

    setupData();
}

</script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: This doesn't explain at all what you did to fix it!

Comment: @LukeSalamone   you should read the discussion below before attempting the solution

Answer (score 2):

Google Apps requires external content to be loaded using ssl. So change all the links to 'https' instead of 'http'.

reg. 'data' not defined: when google visualization loads, it calls *drawVisualization* using `google.setOnLoadCallback()`. In *drawVisualization*, you are using 'data'. However, it isn't yet defined, since you define it only later when you call *handleQueryResponse*. so make sure that 'data' is defined within *drawVisualization*.

Comment: those docs need proper permissions. make them public so that we can view them.

Comment: correct. in that case it'll work because (eg1) 'data' is defined within *drawChart()*, which is executed immediately after google visualization loads. so nothing is undefined there.

Comment: The eg1 was clear.. but eg2 is kind of difficult for me to combine when the data is not difined. Im not really an expertise... Could you please give me a visible alternative... I cant figure out a solution...